# Code to add two 4bit numbers in verilog doesn't work

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga, hdl

I have a code that adds two 4 bit numbers; unfortunately it is not working for every case even though the formulas are really simple and I don't find the problem...

```
module part2(SW, LEDG, LEDR);

    input [17:0] SW;
    output [17:0] LEDR;
    output [4:0] LEDG;

    //Red lights for each one
    assign LEDR[17:0] = SW[17:0];

    //Wires between adders.
    wire carry[2:0];

    //Add the first digits of A and B
    full_adder F0(SW[4], SW[0], SW[8], LEDG[0], carry[0]);
    //Add the second digits of A and B
    full_adder F1(SW[3], SW[1], carry[0], LEDG[1], carry[1]);
    //Add the third digits of A and B
    full_adder F2(SW[6], SW[2], carry[1], LEDG[2], carry[2]);
    //Add the last digits of A and B
    full_adder F3(SW[7], SW[3], carry[2], LEDG[3], LEDG[4]);

    endmodule

module full_adder(A, B, CI, S, CO);

    input A, B, CI;
    output S, CO;

    //Sum
    assign S = A ^ B ^ CI;

    //Carry out
    assign CO = (A & B) | (CI & A) | (CI & B);

endmodule
```

It seems to work for most cases but look what happens with 1 and 10:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo in your code:

```
full_adder F1(SW[3], SW[1], carry[0], LEDG[1], carry[1]);
```

should instead be

```
full_adder F1(SW[5], SW[1], carry[0], LEDG[1], carry[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add your two 4-bit numbers together and let Verilog deal with the specifics.

```
assign LEDG = {1'b0,SW[7:4]} + {1'b0,SW[3:0]};
```

I've mapped the 4-bit inputs in the calculation to 5 bits to ensure that the synthesizer deals with the carry.